# Django admin not accepting latin-based alphabet

Tags: python, django

I am having problem when writing Croatian alphabet letters in django admin.

This is the error I get:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 13-14: ordinal not
>   in range(128)

I've made changes in my settings:

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr-HR'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('hr', 'Hrvatski'),
)
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'UTF-8'
```

This translates django-admin to Croatian, but Django still doesn't except Croatian letters.

I added this on top of models.py, views.py and admin.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I changed `__str__` to `__unicode__` in models

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.title, self.description)
```

After changing my models.py letters like č,ć,đ become ?,?,?

This is what I put in master.html for my templates:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What am I missing? Can somebody give me a hint?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? You should define `__str__` in Python 3, and `__unicode__` in Python 2. Which database are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.9 , mysql database

Comment: Check the character set for MySQL - there are [some suggestions in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#creating-your-database).

Comment: Thank you. I drop my database and create a new one using CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8; Now It all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your database is using UTF-8. You can specify UTF-8 when creating a MySQL database:

```
CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#creating-your-database) for more info.